# Why does lldb produce a memory dump file way larger than requested?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Running the following command in lldb debugger in Xcode

```
memory read pArr --outfile ~/pArr.dump --count 5081160 --force
```

produces a file of size around 25MB, instead of the expected 5MB. And it's not exactly 5 times larger than the requested size, just close to it.

Am I doing something wrong, or may it be a problem with lldb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical `memory read`, not dumping to file, writes a hex dump. That is, it's not writing the raw bytes from memory, it's formatting them to a human-readable representation. Have you looked at your file? I suspect that's what you'll find, in which case it's obvious why it's much larger than the number of bytes dumped. Each byte of memory is represented by several characters (bytes) in the output representation.

There's a `-b`/`--binary` option to `memory read` that may do what you are apparently expecting.